# "fatal: this operation must be run in a work tree" running `git diff` on a sshfs-win mapped drive

Tags: git

I get `fatal: this operation must be run in a work tree` when running `git diff` on a `sshfs-win` mapped drive.

**All git operations work fine** *except* `git diff`. Is there a fix?